# Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade

Tags: windows, mysql, database

I resized an Azure VM and now the MySQL DB running in Windows inside the VM is dead.  I am seeing the below fatal error on startup.  I tried to run mysql_upgrade as it suggests but that just errors out saying it cannot connect.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

```
2016-07-12T09:59:48.426367Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-07-12T09:59:48.426367Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-07-12T09:59:48.426367Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-07-12T09:59:48.426367Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-07-12T09:59:48.426367Z 0 [Note] Shared memory setting up listener
2016-07-12T09:59:48.438315Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2016-07-12T09:59:48.455584Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at     160712  9:59:48
2016-07-12T09:59:48.455584Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is     damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade.
2016-07-12T09:59:48.455584Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Start this with skip-grant-tables and then run mysql_upgrade.

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally solved!
This worked for me : `/etc/init.d/mysqld start --skip-grant-tables && mysql_upgrade`

Once the upgrade is successful, you do this: `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`
Or, you can stop and start mysqld seperately.

I had been locked in mysql errors from yesterday on Centos 6.

This really saves your day if you installed a different version of mysql on your system while the system already had another version of mysql installed on it.
It's very much likely to get different sorts of errors in this situation.

--skip-grant-tables can come in handy to unlock you out of this situation.
If you have some security concerns, check this : [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) on how to use this option with security.

**More details on --skip-grant-tables:**
This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges, and disables account-management statements such as ALTER USER and SET PASSWORD.
Source: [Click here to learn more on skip grant from official mysql site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Kruthika

Comment: after the password is not working

Comment: I had to add `skip-grant-tables` to `my.cnf` for it to work. I followed this: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001659169-MySQL-fails-to-start-after-an-upgrade-mysql-user-table-is-damaged

Answer (score 0):

Another flag the [mysql upgrade documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrade-binary-package.html) doesn't fully mention, is: `--force`.

In my past upgrades, a failing `/mysql_upgrade -u root -p` command showed this notice:

> This installation of MySQL is already upgraded use --force
> if you still need to run mysql_upgrade

If the `skip-grant-tables` option fails, as if often does for me on Mac OS X... The last resort is to force upgrade all tables with: `./mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force`.

In addition to `ALTER TABLE` or `REPAIR TABLE` afterwards, to ensure all tables are fully rebuilt.